# Press submit on enter button

Tags: html, angular

I have this login form:

```
<div class="form col-md-12 center-block">
      <br />
      <div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" (keyup.enter)="focusElement(psw, $event)" autofocus type="text" class="form-control input-lg" [(ngModel)]="model.username" placeholder="Username" name="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" #psw (keyup.enter)="focusElement(btn, $event)" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" [(ngModel)]="model.password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button #btn (click)="login()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" [disabled]="loading" type="text">login</button>
        <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger">
        {{error}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

When page is loading, my focus set on username input, then i click enter, and my focus go to password, and then i must click enter only TWO times, and after i login in next page.

And i would click enter like this: after username, and when i wrote password click ONE time on enter, and login button submitted.

Comment: Remove your (keyup.enter): the standard way to navigate between fields is to use TAB. Make your button a button with type "submit" instead of "text". Use a <form> element with ngSubmit to login. In short... use standard HTML.

Comment: @JBNizet That will probably fix it

Comment: @JB Nizet i use enter for go to next input tag

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't. There's a standard key to navigate through form controls, known and used by everybody familiar with computers, which is Tab. Enter is the standard key, known by everybody familiar with computers, to submit the form. There is no reason not to use these standard keys, and let the browser handle the navigation and standard keys.

Comment: @JB Nizet Enter - is not standart key to navigate.

Answer (score -1):

can you use (submit) method of the form element?

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand what does mean "use submit method"

Comment: hi @divya, you should provide more developed answer with, when is possible, code sample to help every body to understand your pruposal